# Trying to create 2 child processes and 1 grandchild that run in order

Tags: c, process, fork, wait

So I am attempting to create 2 child processes and one grandchild process off the first child. I am attempting to run the first child process then the grandchild then the second child with the parent calling out the pid when the process is finished. I am completely stuck - I have numerous code versions of the code but can not get them to fire in the right order. Any help, advice or links would be greatly appreciated.

Desired output would be

-I am the first child

----I am the grandchild

I'm the parent, first child has pid 21505

-I am the first child, grandchild has pid 21506

-Try again

--I am the second child

-- -->Second child: 1317 bytes transferred.

I'm the parent again, second child has pid 21507

Parent - Child 21507 is done

-Try again

**** should see first 20 lines of lab4.c file here

Parent - Other child 21505 is done

```
int main(int* argc, char* args[])
{
pid_t child1, child2, gchild; //process ids
child1 = fork();           //Create the two child processes
if (child1 == 0)
{ // parent
    child2 = fork();
    if (child2 == 0)
    { //parent
        printf("P: first child has pid %d\n", child1);
        printf("P: second child has pid %d\n", child2);

        pid_t wpid; // process id that is finished
        int status; //status code returned by process  
                    //Wait for all child processes to complete
        while ((wpid = wait(&status)) > 0)
        {
            if (wpid > 0)
            {
                printf("P: Child %d is done \n", wpid);
            }
        };

        exit(0); //exit main parent process
    }
    else
    {
        //Second process's code

        printf("SC: I am the second child.\n");
        int totalBytes = 0; //total number of bytes in the file we are going to read in
        char buffer[2056]; //file contents size 2056 bytes
        ssize_t read_bytes = 0; //Bytes from each chunk get placed here temporarily

        ///Read in file contents: home/common/lab_sourcefile
        int fd_in = open("/home/COIS/3380/lab4_sourcefile", O_RDONLY);//open the file
        do
        {
            //read the file chunk by chunk to the buffer
            read_bytes = read(fd_in, buffer, (size_t)2056);

            // End of file or error.
            if (read_bytes <= 0)
            {
                break; //done reading file
            }

            //Save the total number of bytes
            totalBytes = totalBytes + read_bytes;
        } while (1); //infinite loop until we are done reading the file

        //Write out contents to: lab4_file_copy
        char filepath[1024]; //temp path
        getcwd(filepath, sizeof(filepath)); //Get the current working directory
        strcat(filepath, "/lab4_file_copy"); //Tack on the filename
        int fd = open(filepath, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH); //open the file. O_RDWR = read and write flag, O_CREAT = create if doesnt exist, S_* flags are permission flags from fstat 
        write(fd, buffer, strlen(buffer)); //write to the file

        close(fd_in);//close file we were reading
        close(fd); //close copy file

        // print out the number of bytes the file
        printf("SC: --> Second child: %d bytes transferred.\n", totalBytes);

        exit(0); //done kill second child process
    }
}
else
{
    //First child process

    printf("FC: I'm the first child.\n");

    //Create the granchild process
    gchild = fork();
    if (gchild == 0)
    {
        printf("GC: I am the grandchild.\n");

        sleep(3); //sleep for 3 seconds

        printf("GC: #### Output start ####\n");
        execlp("head", "head", "-n", "20", "l.c", NULL); //this should exit automatically
        printf("ERROR: execlp command failed\n");//This will only run if the execlp process fails
        exit(1); //FAILED!
    }
    else
    {
        //Output the granchild pid
        printf("FC: I am the first child, grandchild has pid %d\n", gchild);
        int grandchildStatus;
        //Wait for grandchild process to be done. Polling...
        while ((waitpid(gchild, &grandchildStatus, WNOHANG)) != gchild)
        {
            printf("FC: Try again\n");
            sleep(1);
        };
        printf("GC: #### Output end ####\n");
        //End of first child. Grandchild must have completed.

        exit(0); //Done. kill first child process
    }
}
```

}

Comment: If you swapped the 3rd and the forth line, you could simply sync with `wait` calls after each fork. If you want them as they are, you'll need an additional sync mechanism. There's plenty to choose from: pipes, signals, shared memory semaphores, etc. Take a pick.

Comment: learn semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two bugs in your program:

- The last `else` part:

  You call `fork` so everything that comes after the `fork` function will be executed in both processes.

  **Both** the parent and the second child will print: "*I am the parent, the first child has pid...*"

  To fix this you'll have to add an `if(child2 == 0)` (within the `else` block)...
- The order of instructions:

  When you start a child process the child process will **really** run the same time as the parent process:

  If one process prints out "*Hello world.*" and the other one prints out "**This is a test.**" you might see the following text on the screen: "**This** *Hello* **is a** *world.* **test.**" (or similar) because both processes are writing to the screen the same time.

  You could use the `waitpid` function in the parent of a child process to wait until the child process has finished to ensure that the child has finished before the parent continues (printing out text).

  If you however want to print the text in the parent process first you'll have to find a way to stop the child and to wait for the parent process to have finished printing.

  You might for example use `raise(SIGSTOP);` to stop the currently running process. In another process use `kill(pid, SIGCONT);` to continue the other process `pid` which is waiting:

  ```
  child = fork();
  if(child == 0)
  {
      raise(SIGSTOP); /* Wait for the parent */
      /* Do something */
  }
  else
  {
      /* Do something */
      kill(child, SIGCONT); /* Tell the child to continue */
  }
  ```

... however: As PSkocik just mentioned even in this case your program may hang - so it is not that easy!

Comment: What if SIGCONT gets sent before SIGSTOP?